# How to remove paths starting with a certain pattern from a list of paths?

Tags: path, filter

Say that I have the following list:

```
vim9script
g:my_paths = ['C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv', 
'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\python310.zip', 
'C\Mypath',
'C\Anotherpath',
'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\DLLs', 
'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib', 
'C\Mypath\Subpath',
'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages', 
'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\win32']
```

I wish to remove all the paths from `g:my_paths` that start with `C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv`.

How to do that?

My attempt was to use the `filter` function in the following way:

```
vim9script
g:to_filter = 'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv'
g:filtered_list = g:my_paths->filter($"v:val !~ '^{g:to_filter}'")
```

But it didn't filter out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're using regular expressions for the filter, so you will have to be careful with backslashes in `g:to_filter`. For example, [`\m`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html?#/%5Cm) would enable magic, and `\M` would disable it. And so on for other characters.

Try with:

```
g:to_filter = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myenv'
```

Or just avoid regular expressions altogether

```
g:to_filter = 'C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv'
g:filtered_list = g:my_paths->filter('stridx(v:val, g:to_filter) != 0')
```

Comment: My problem is that g_to_filter is automatically generated in my script. Do you suggest to use `substitute()` the \ with \\ before using `g:to_filter` ?

Comment: @Barzi2001 I edited to add an alternative

Comment: Much better to avoid regex. Thanks. I would say that solve my initial question.